# Delete the current line in Android Studio?

Tags: keyboard, android, cursor

I want to select the entire line my cursor is on so I can delete it. By using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> I can move my cursor to the end of the line. But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> doesn't work... What's the alternative(s)? Thanks.

Comment: Ctrl-K? If it is using default OS X keybindings there should be a giant amount of bindings.

Answer (score 2):

The <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> can solve my final problem: I want to delete the line the cursor is on. And the cursor doesn't have to be at the end of the line you want to delete, it can be anywhere in the line.